# Recommended Tools For Troubleshooting Nested Blocks

Tags: objective-c, debugging, objective-c-blocks

What tools might exist for troubleshooting issues with nested blocks (e.g. - identifying captured variables, retain cycles, etc.)? I would also be interested in knowing your recommended reference materials for working with nested blocks.

Comment: @animuson This is not off-topic. I do not think that you understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking about what tools to use for memory management analysis.

I start with the Allocations instrument and, in particular, with [Heapshot Analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).   It is quite good at identifying any permanent growth over repetitive events (but can be used in the non-repetitive case, too).

You can turn on tracking of retain/release events and see if any of the Block helper functions (generated by the compiler) are the source of your retains.

And, of course, "build and analyze" your code.   The compiler has become quite adept at picking up retain cycles through blocks, especially with ARC enabled. (Though there is a long way to go).

There isn't much in the way of tools to identify the captured state in a block.

---

On the Allocations instrument, click the little (i) and turn on both *Only track active allocations* and *Record reference counts*.

The former will reduce the data set Instruments tracks significantly, making it snappier, while the latter will track all retain/release events to any given object, including the backtrace of the source of the event.

Comment: Bill, thank you. When doing heapshot analysis, I know how to identify what code was responsible for creating an object, but I do not know if there are any tools to call out what other code may be responsible for retaining it. How do I turn on the tracking of retain/release events that you refer to? I have been Googling, and I'm not seeing it. Thanks again!